# How do I install ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates? NOT CORE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have to admit I find this incredibly frustrating. I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2er6mMglRVg (Asp.net MVC 6 web api with angular js)

I'm unable to progress at all because it needs "ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates" and now that Asp.net CORE has come around; its difficult to obtain these templates.

This happens so often when I attempt to start following something with Visual Studio. **Why can't I just download these templates?**

So far the suggestions were to upgrade/reinstall visual studio so I have wasted more time downloading visual studio 2015 update 2 and installing that. Of course when the installation finished there were no asp.net templates. The next suggestion is to just install it from the links through visual studio, which links to a MS link that now points to CORE. Installing CORE does not give me these templates.

I don't particularly care that 5 is dead and core is the new way. There aren't many core tutorials yet. For the time being I wanted to follow this but of i'm blocked at the very first step. Surely I can just find a template file and import it in, but now i've installed core I think I will have MORE pain getting rid of that and getting the ASP.NET 5 templates installed.

Comment: Be careful wit your tone. You won't get many answers with such an aggressive attitude

Comment: You have made quite a few negative assumptions and accusations here in the question body and in your responses to answers.  Why can't you just download the templates?  **Because that set of libraries was never an official release, only a "preview" of what the release libraries might be**.  The license for preview copies never guarantees that they will be available and usable forever, and most developers wouldn't expect to continue to reliably use out of date libraries anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be just template files that you need since there were **significant** changes to the framework and tooling since the rename of "ASP.NET 5" to "ASP.NET CORE". So in the end of the day, you'd need ASP.NET Beta 8 (included in VS 2015 **Update 1**) in order to be able to see ASP.NET 5 templates and to be able to **actually** use them. It's good enough for learning purposes if you're following a tutorial targeting earlier versions of the SDK.

Now that I've answered your question, my recommendation is that you forget that tutorial and focus on what's present and the documentation. There is plenty of information already for RC 2 and you'll be up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 5 has been renamed to ASP.NET Core since RC1. ASP.NET Core is not to be confused with .NET Core. ASP.NET Core runs on .NET Core, as well as Full .NET. Chances are you are actually looking for ASP.NET Core templates since MVC6 is only compatible with this version of the framework.

Comment: I thought I made it pretty clear I am looking for "ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates" and I installed ASP.NET Core, which did **does not** include the templates

Comment: So you are indeed looking for the templates that ran under the beta8 and before. Is that right? Those templates do not have a go to production license and a lot has changed in between. If it's still what you want, look for beta8 templates in github (https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/tree/6.0.0-beta8). You should be able to build the installer or something like that.

Comment: I don't know where "beta8" came from. This is for some introductory learning with angular and mvc. If there is a tutorial for using asp.net core instead of asp.net 5 i'd be more than happy to run with that but I haven't found much material. As such, I feel it will be better starting with this tutorial and I can move to core down the track (when there is more material on the internet). He selects "Empty Web" which looks like it might correspond to https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/tree/6.0.0-beta8/src/BaseTemplates/EmptyWeb can I just import this template from file?

Comment: @MVCHell2: It's software that's still in development, names change, templates change. That's what you have to expect when using unreleased software. Also outdated tutorials won't be much help to you anyways. All you need is in the ASP.NET Core documentation to get started. Either you live with that or wait until its released and there are more updated tutorials for. RTM is aimed for end of June, so you better wait to August or End of 2016 to get started with it. And with your tone you'd be more than happy that anyone makes even an effort to answer you

Comment: So you suggest just giving up and waiting till the end of 2016 to beginning development simply because MS no longer makes it trivial to download **template** files? LOL. Also you would assume once moving from ASP.NET 5 to ASP.NET CORE that 5's development ceased...

Answer (score 0):

If you want ASP.NET Core ( ASP.NET 5 previously ) templates in your VS instance, go to **VS Setup => Modify =>**, mark **Web Developer Tools** and reinstall it again it won't take much time to install.

If it still does not appear in your VS instance, then install .NET Core from [here](http://dot.net/) on your PC first, here you will also find **Visual Studio MSI installer**. This will surely install ASP.NET Core RC2 templates in your VS instance.

Comment: I went modify and that bit is already installed. I'll try unchecking it, then rechecking it.

Answer (score 0):

Downloads ASP.NET 5 RC 1 here.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49959

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.